# ASP.net MVC Data Table Ajax Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Im creating my firts MVC app, this app should thisplays in Data Table all the info Stored in my Tables "Clientes", this table  was created using SQL Server andis being link to my project using Entity  Framework.

but when i run my code I got this error message:

```
DataTables warning: table id=myDataTable - Ajax error. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7


@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" class="tablecontainer" />
    <title>Index</title>
    <!--Hojas de estilo ( Archivos planos de texto para poner estilos a mis etiquetas)-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
    <link href="~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Style/miprimerStyle.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <!--Ancho del padre-->
    <div class="tamaño" id="tamaño"> 
        <!--a es hipervinculos-->
        <a class="popup btn btn-primary Margin20" href="/home/save/0" >Agregar un nuevo cliente </a>
        <table id="myDataTable">
            <thead>
                <!--Fila-->
                <tr>
                    <!--Columna-->
                    <th>Nombre</th> 
                    <th>Apellido</th>
                    <th>Telefono</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
    </div>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var oTable = $('#myDataTable').DataTable({
                "ajax": {
                    "url" : '/home/GetEmployees',
                    "type" : "get",
                    "datatype" : "json"
                },
                "columns": [
                    { "data": "Nombre", "autoWidth": true },
                    { "data": "Apellido", "autoWidth": true },
                    { "data": "Telefono", "autoWidth": true },
                ]
            })
        })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is my Home Controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

namespace TestDeConocimientos.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        public ActionResult GetEmployees()
        {
            using (TerasysDBEntities1 dc = new TerasysDBEntities1())
            {
               var clientes = dc.Clientes.OrderBy(a => a.Nombre).ToList();
               return Json(new { data = clientes }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I also put a breakpoint at  the line:

```
var clientes = dc.Clientes.OrderBy(a => a.Nombre).ToList();
```

and I could See that   ll the Data is perfectly stored on the Var "Clients"

What is happening Here?

Comment: According to the error message, Ajax call failed. The page http://datatables.net/tn/7 explains how to get Http error from your browser. Please follow these instructions and post the information here.

Comment: check this , it might help :https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1114208/Beginners-Guide-for-Creating-GridView-in-ASP-NET-M

Comment: @derloopkat 
2jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
:3423/home/GetEmployees?_=1497233865564 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: Try comment out two lines: <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>

Comment: @Tomato32 Stills Not Working

Comment: @derloopkat  I tought that this line:

return Json(new { data = clientes }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

is making the required cast

Comment: Based on your Ajax code, I believe your DataTable is expecting something like {
    "data": [
        {
            "Nombre": "Tiger",
            "Apellido": "Woods",
            "Telefono": "005 5698"
        },
        {
            "Nombre": "Pete",
            "Apellido": "May",
            "Telefono": "005 9968"
        }
    ]
}

Comment: @derloopkat I solved  it By adding

dc.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved:

```
public ActionResult GetEmployees()
        {
            using (TerasysDBEntities1 dc = new TerasysDBEntities1())
            {
                dc.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
                var clientes = dc.Clientes.OrderBy(a => a.Nombre).ToList();
                return Json(new { data = clientes }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
```